# xsl 1.x how do I change the output depending on the selection?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

this is What I have tried otherwise always works.  If type = 'WEEKLY' I need it to output "W"

```
  <xsl:for-each select="times/weekly_monthly">
    <tr>
  <td>
  <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="type='WEEKLY'">W</xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
  otherwise always works
  </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
  </td>

  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

if I take out the the choose, it iterates just fine. 
here is the xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
        <?xml-stylesheet type= "text/xsl" href= "test.xsl"?>  

        <!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->

        <times>
        <weekly_monthly>
        <type>
        WEEKLY
        </type>
        </weekly_monthly>
        <weekly_monthly>
        <type>
        MONTHLY
        </type>
        </weekly_monthly>
        <weekly_monthly>
        <type>
        NULL
        </type>
        </weekly_monthly>
        </times>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `<type>` node contains white-spaces. Use `normalize-space()` functions, i.e.:

```
normalize-space(type) = 'WEEKLY'
```

or `contains()` function:

```
contains(type, 'WEEKLY')
```

Comment: that makes total sense about the white space when I think about it.